# How do I run a bash-script from a system service?

Tags: python, linux, bash, service, tmux

So I'm trying to launch a tmux screen from a bash script which will then host a (python) discordbot. That bash script should in turn be launched from a system service so that the discordbot always launches with the physical server itself.
It seems that it gets stuck somewhere for some reason... I've been looking for ages for a solution but haven't been able to find one.

Here is the system service output:

```
● ubuntubot.service - UbuntuBot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ubuntubot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-08-13 18:39:26 CEST; 1min 58s ago
   Main PID: 27366 (tmux: server)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 19060)
     Memory: 4.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ubuntubot.service
             ├─27366 /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s ubuntubot
             └─27367 -bash
```

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=UbuntuBot
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/flynn/Minecraft/CreativeServer/DiscordBot/launchbot.sh start
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
```

And this is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script launches the Ubuntubot in a different tmux screen

#Start tmux ubuntu-session:
/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s ubuntubot

#Start UbuntuBot
/usr/bin/tmux send-keys -t ubuntubot "python3 ~/Minecraft/CreativeServer/DiscordBot/Ubuntubot.py" Enter
```

Maybe this is a horrible way to do it i have honestly no idea... I just need some help cause this is taking me wayyy to long on my own:)

Comment: What the `status` command shows? You can check `journalctl --user` also

Comment: I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a more appropriate place to ask this. Or https://superuser.com/ maybe.

Comment: Don't use tmux for system services.

Comment: With @mama; don't use tmux here. Just run the Ubuntubot.py from the bash script.

Comment: Also I wouldn't use `Restart=always` as you might have to stop the service for longer than 5 seconds at some point. `Restart=on-failure` is sufficient.